# MySQL dud entry in table

Tags: mysql

I have an dud entry in MySQL table where I am not able to update or do anything with. This is causing issues on the application as it shows an outstanding task but we cant clear the error. I am wondering is there a way to correct this issue?

```
+------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| id   | type_id | status | created_at          |
+------+---------+--------+---------------------+
| 8706 |     174 |      0 | 2014-05-16 14:13:13 |
| 8707 |     174 |      9 | 2014-05-16 14:18:29 |
| 8708 |     174 |      7 | 2014-05-16 14:19:54 |
| 8709 |     174 |      7 | 2014-05-16 14:21:20 |
| 8711 |     239 |      0 | 2014-05-20 02:14:57 |
| 8712 |     239 |      0 | 2014-05-20 02:21:20 |
| 8713 |     239 |      0 | 2014-05-20 02:28:19 |
| 8714 |     239 |      0 | 2014-05-20 02:31:02 |
+------+---------+--------+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The snapshots are below

```
select id, type_id, status,created_at from device where id > 8705 and id < 8715;
```

[image: Missing Entry]

```
select id, type_id, status,created_at from device where id = 8710;
```

[image: Missing Entry 2]

I am wondering if there is any way this can be corrected and get the application working properly again?

Comment: What's the problem? You shouldn't assume that there are no gaps in the ID sequence.

Comment: An entry existed at one point that other tables depended on and from the understanding of the tool, there should have been no deleted entries on this table. I was able to clue in that it no longer existed so i had to make it exist to fix the rest of the tool.

Comment: You should implement foreign key constraints, so that rows that are references in another table cannot be deleted.

Comment: I will look into that. thank you for the help. I also inherited the tool from others in the past, it requires lots of work.

Comment: I have this same dud entry, but I have no missing IDs. So, I'm not able to resolve it the way you did.

Comment: use an update statement instead of a insert statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out as the entry doesnt exist, by creating an insert command, it corrects the issue.

```
insert into device (id, type_id, name,status,created_at) values (8710, 174, "deleted entry",0,0);
```

Comment: solves the immediate problem but does nothing for future issues.  I would go with Barmar's solution if you can.  Assuming non-myIsam tables.

Comment: I am keeping the tool alive for 6 months to a Year. I agree if we have to design a new one, to set this up but in this case, I am going to fix the few bugs and keep it working until it can be retired.