# Default NULL entry in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, null, create-table

**Not a duplicate of [MySQL dud entry in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448449/mysql-dud-entry-in-table), since I have no gaps in my id column and inserting did not resolve it.**

I have a table with the following schema, but there is a default entry is created with NULL in all the columns. This NULL row is returned for every select query even if I add "film_id IS NOT NULL" as a clause.

```
CREATE TABLE film(
    film_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    film_title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    film_release_year YEAR NOT NULL
);
```

The output of "select * from film"

[image: table value with NULL entry]

The output of "select * from film where film_id = 27" note:film_id is a primary key.

[image]

I get the NULL entry for all select statements. I can see it since the table is created.

Comment: What do you get if you select count(*) from film?

Comment: that is universal for a new line and exxist not only in mysql, acess , ssms and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's just a quirk of MySQL Workbench that lets you insert rows if you click those `NULL` squares and enter values there. That row doesn't exist in your table.